# Getting the initiator for an NSMenuItem

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, desktop-application, nsmenu

I have a view with 3 images which have there own `@property` in their class. 
When I right click one of these images, I show a `NSMenu` with submenu which has `NSMenuItems`.
All the items are send to the `IBAction` called `- (IBAction)selectImage:(id)sender` with each a different `tag`. The `sender` is, of course, the `NSMenuItem`. How can I find out which image the user right clicked upon? So I an basically looking for the caller to the parent of the `sender`.

Or maybe, I am building my menu all wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're approaching the problem the wrong way. Instead of setting an explicit target on your menu items, use the [First Responder](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/EventOverview/EventArchitecture/EventArchitecture.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000060i-CH3-SW7) (or `nil`if you're doing it in code).

By default, the first responder will be the view that owns the contextual menu ("For a context menu, the search is restricted to the responder chain of the window in which the context menu was displayed, starting with the associated view" according the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/EventOverview/EventArchitecture/EventArchitecture.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000060i-CH3-SW2)).

Therefore, if you subclass your `NSImageView` and implement the actions that you need there, it will, by default, receive the messages. They can be a simple redirection to your controller object, but you will know which view was clicked on this way (because it's `self` in this case!)

---

*This answer is an edit of this previous answer, which is significantly less elegant:*

Start by creating a subclass of NSMenu (let's call it `PPMenu`) that has an additional property to store a weak reference to your image view (let's call it `imageView`). Set that class as your menu's class in your XIB, and set the menu as the image view's context menu there as well (or, if they don't exist in the XIB, just add an outlet).

Now, if you override `-menuForEvent:` is your `NSImageView` subclass, you'll be able to customize the context menu... Start by calling `super` there to retrieve the `PPMenu` instance (if it is set up in IB, otherwise use the outlet), and set the `imageView` property that you've added to `self` (since you're in the image view code).

Now, in your action's code, you can use `((PPMenu*)(sender.menu)).imageView` to retrieve the image view associated with the menu.

Answer (score 1):

You would override [`-menuForEvent:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSView_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSView/menuForEvent:) in your view class and store a reference to the event, remember the location, or determine which image was hit and remember that. Then, in the action method, you would use that remembered event/location/image index to determine how to respond.

Of course, to get the event location in the view's coordinates, you would do:

```
NSPoint point = [self convertPoint:event.locationInWindow fromView:nil];
```

When testing if that point is in a particular part of the view, you should use:

```
if ([self mouse:point inRect:rectOfInterest])
    // ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Just remember the image you clicked in your right click event handler.

```
#pragma mark - mouse events

- (void)rightMouseDown:(NSEvent *)event
{
  [super rightMouseDown:event]; // if you don't want to push events to parent view - remove this line
  NSPoint eventLocation = [event locationInWindow]; // get mouse location in window coordinates
  NSPoint localLocation = [self convertPoint:eventLocation fromView:nil]; // get mouse location in view coordinates
  selectedImageView = nil; // set it nil each time right mouse down
  NSArray *images = @[imageView0, imageView1, imageView2]; // all your image view outlets, check if they aren't nil
  for (NSImageView *imageView in images)
    if (NSPointInRect(localLocation, imageView.frame))
    {
      selectedImageView = imageView; // selectedImageView should be a class member
      break;
    }
}

#pragma mark - menu actions

- (IBAction)selectImage:(id)sender
{
  if (selectedImageView)
  {
    // your code here
  }
}
```

This was a light version of what you need to be done. But let's think user is pushing right mouse down near the image0, then drag cursor off the image and then releases the mouse. For this you should override another mouse event handler `rightMouseUp` just to check the cursor still above the `selectedImageView`

```
#pragma mark - mouse events

//...

- (void)rightMouseUp:(NSEvent *)event
{
  [super rightMouseUp:event];
  if (!selectedImageView)
    return; // nothing to check here
  NSPoint eventLocation = [event locationInWindow]; 
  NSPoint localLocation = [self convertPoint:eventLocation fromView:nil]; 
  if (!NSPointInRect(localLocation, selectedImageView.frame)) // the mouse not above the selectedImageView
    selectedImageView = nil;
  else
    {
      // there may be NSMenu instance initializing
    }
}
```

Comment: It's not enough to use `-rightMouseDown:`. Contextual menus can be initiated by Control-click, too, which doesn't go through that method. It's possible there are additional ways, such as Accessibility. Also, contextual menus appear on the mouse-down. Moving the cursor away before the mouse-up doesn't matter and is, in fact, normal. I don't think the view will receive it, though, since I think the mouse is capture by the menu tracking. I haven't checked that last bit, though.

Comment: @KenThomases well, you're right, I just pointed on remembering imageView, not touching menu instantiating process at all.

Comment: Hmm? I didn't mean to suggest that you needed to instantiate a menu. My point is that `-rightMouseDown:` may not be called at all when the user wants a contextual menu. Because they don't have to right-click. Also, the OP never mentioned image **views**. In fact, the suggestion is that there are just images in a single view.

Comment: @KenThomases hmm, I didn't think about it. Very suitable assumption.